# VGA or HDMI on Dell U2713HM

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, resolution, hdmi, vga

I just bought a Dell u2713hm that supports 2560 * 1440 resolution.
My laptop (with Geforce GT540M) obviously has only HDMI and VGA port.
I will use the monitor only for my job, so Photoshop, Autocad and Rhino (no movies or videogames). I have 2 questions and hope you can help me:

1. HDMI imput seems to be limited to 1920x1080@60Hz, while the VGA reaches 2048x1152@60Hz. You think I have to still use HDMI or I can go for the VGA with a resolution a bit higher?
2. Is there any breakthrough (converter or settings) that let me reach the 2560x1440 resolution with my laptop?

Comment: Both HDMI and VGA are capable of supporting 2560x1440 (see [answer](http://superuser.com/a/252228/57398). You may be limited by your graphics card. Its settings manager program or OS's display control panel should show what resolutions are available to you.